# trouble loading tidyverse, issues with rlang

Tags: r, tidyverse, rlang

I get this message when using library(tidyverse)

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.5 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.9 is required
```

I tried removing the rlang package, and tried `install.packages("rlang_0.4.10")` and `install.packages("rlang")` in the console, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: May you add the output of `sessionInfo()` in your R session so other may know better what might cause the issue you got into?